# Не работает валидация md-autocomplete Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular2, typescript

Валидация других полей без директивы md-autocomplete работает. C md-autocomplete ничего не происходит, подскажите, что не так?

component.html:

```
  <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Регион" formControlName="region" [mdAutocomplete]="region" name="region" [formControl]="regionCtrl">
            <md-error *ngIf="form.get('region').touched && form.get('region').hasError('required')">
                <strong>Пожалуйста, выберите регион</strong>
            </md-error>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-autocomplete #region="mdAutocomplete">
            <md-option *ngFor="let region of filteredRegions | async" [value]="region">
                {{ region }}
            </md-option>
        </md-autocomplete>
```

component.ts:

```
export class CarComponent implements OnInit {
      form: FormGroup;

      regionCtrl: FormControl;
      filteredRegions: any;

public regions = [
    'Архангельск',
    'Астрахань',
    'Барнаул',
    'Белгород',
    'Благовещенск',
    ...

 constructor(
    private carService: CarService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private http:Http
  ) { 
    this.regionCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredRegions = this.regionCtrl.valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .map(name => this.filterRegions(name)); 
    }

    filterRegions(val: string) {
    return val ? this.regions.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0)
               : this.regions;
  };


  ngOnInit() {
    this.carService.car$
      .subscribe(car => {
        this.initForm(car);
      });
  }

  initForm(car: CarProfile) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      region: [car.region, Validators.required]
    });
  }
```